# Set mx:MenuBar left and right padding to zero

Tags: apache-flex

Looks like the only way to do it is to subclass MenuBar.
Which method and how should I override?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [left](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#style%3aleft) and [right](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#style%3aright) styles? and setting them to zero?

```
menuBar.setStyle('left',0);
menuBar.setStyle('right',0);
```

Comment: left and right set margins not padding (margin is outside of the border and padding is inside)

Comment: The set the left and right on the MenuBarItem? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/menuClasses/MenuBarItem.html